# Дано некоторое число. Определить, можно ли получить это число путем возведения числа 3 в некоторую степень

Tags: javascript

```
let number = parseInt(prompt("Введите что-бы проверить можно ли получить число из 3-ки в степени: "));

// if (number % 3 === 0 && number ) {
//     document.write("Число можно получить ");
// }   else {
//     document.write("Число нельзя получить");
// }
```

Дано некоторое число. Определить, можно ли получить это число путем возведения числа 3 в некоторую степень. (Например, числа 9, 81 можно получить, а 13 - нельзя)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function isPowerOfThree(num) {
  while (num % 3 == 0) {
    num /= 3;
  }
  return num == 1;
}

console.log(isPowerOfThree(81));
console.log(isPowerOfThree(126));
```

---

> Как это сделать без фунции?

Кхм, кхм.

```
while (number % 3 == 0) {
    number /= 3;
}
document.write((number == 1)? "Число можно получить " : "Число нельзя получить");
```

Comment: Как это сделать без фунции?